# Q: How to reject hidden email signs in Apple Sign In?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

I have a product that works as serve customers via login with email. I implement Apple-Sign-In to the app and need to know if the email is hidden or not. In another way, I do not want to make user sign-in through to the app because I can not match users in DB with the users who sign with Apple-Sign-In with hiding their email. My request scopes are like below;

```
request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
```

but the user can hide its email.

Is there any way to achieve?

Comment: I bet you can't. This is precisely the purpose of Apple Signin, protecting user privacy. I think you can access a userId

Comment: @CZ54 Yeah possible

Comment: I know am pretty late but anyone searching for these can have a look 

you can simply check if
`let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` and then 
 `if appleIDCredential.email != nil` 
 if its nil that means it's hidden